# Brushless DC servo Motor

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am very very very new to ROS so i apologize if this is a dumb question.

I have several 48 Volt DC brushless servo motors for a large scale robotics project.
They take in 8 bit ascii command from an rs 232.

I have done some searching, but i was curious if anyone has seen any stack in ROS that would handle some input output on rs232 so i could read and write some commands to my motors. i.e read some joystick code in and output certain ascii commands based on joystick reads. Generic Joystick values coming from say the ubuntu joystick library

The motors have a proprietary program from the manufacture but it is terrible. We are using a linux system for the vehicle and i was curious if ROS has some solutions for us. As i said i apologize if this is not a correct post.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34356/brushless-dc-servo-motor/) by [automagp68](https://answers.ros.org/users/2402/automagp68/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that William Woodall has written a pretty good serial library that can be used with ROS.  It is available as a unary stack on [Github](https://github.com/wjwwood/serial).

This library just handles the basic serial transactions, which you can then wrap in your own ROS node.

There is an example of interfacing with an AX2550 motor controller as part of the [Auburn-Automow](https://github.com/Auburn-Automow/ax2550) Github account, if you are looking for a good reference for using the library.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-20**:
Yes that one is good too

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please search the ROS [packages](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php) for joysticks or whatever else you need. In some, but not all packages they have tutorials you can follow. Those should help get you going.

If serial is all you want, then there is a [cerial](http://ros.org/wiki/cereal_port) package I have played with too that works good

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1